# While Mouse press event. Prototype JS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, mouse, prototypejs, dom-events, pressed

I would like to know if someone knows how to make a function repeat over and over while the mouse is press, I don't know how to make it work. I know in prototype you can take events like

```
$('id').observe("click",function(event){}) 
$('id').observe("leave",function(event){})
$('id').observe("change",function(event){})
//etc...
```

but is something like `$('id').observe("whilemousepress",function(event){})` :P
//I know there is not any event in Javascript but I would like to emulate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't comment on the prototype specifics, but you could probably do this by creating an interval using [`setInterval()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) that is started on `mousedown` and is stopped using [`.clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval) on `mouseup`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an event for when the mouse is down `mousedown` and one for when the mouse is up `mouseup`. Just start your events when the mouse is pressed and stop them when the button is released.

```
$('id').observe("mousedown",function(event){
    // Do whatever you want
})

$('id').observe("mouseup",function(event){
    // Stop the events starts when the mouse when down
})
```

Answer (score 0):

ok... I guess both are correct what I did is :

```
        $('right').observe('mousedown',function(event){ intervalRigth = setInterval(this.name + ".dosomething()",50); }.bind(this));
        $('left').observe('mousedown',function(event){ intervalLeft = setInterval(this.name + ".dosomething()",50); }.bind(this));


        $('right').observe('mouseup',function(event){ clearInterval(intervalRigth ); }.bind(this));
        $('left').observe('mouseup',function(event){ clearInterval(intervalLeft ); }.bind(this));
```

//so I guess a mix of both answer are right thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var MouseUtils = (function() {
  'use strict';
  // VARIABLES
  var _isScrolling = false;
  var _buttonsArray = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]; // 0 left, 2 right, 1 middle, other.. extra buttons, gaming mouses
  var _mousePressed = false;

  //EVENT LISTENERS
  var _init = function(w, d) {
    w.onscroll = function() {
      _isScrolling = true;
    };
    d.onmousedown = function(e) {
      _buttonsArray[e.button] = true;
      _mousePressed = true;
    };
    d.onmouseup = function(e) {
      _buttonsArray[e.button] = false;
      _mousePressed = false;
    };
    d.oncontextmenu = function() { // this is mandatory for clicks down|ups works well
      return false;
    };
    return this;
  };

  // TIMERS
  var _scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if(_isScrolling) {
      _isScrolling = false;
    }
  }, 500);

  // EXPOSED
  var _isLeftPressed = function() {
    return _buttonsArray[0];
  };
  var _isRightPressed = function() {
    return _buttonsArray[2];
  };
  var _isMiddlePressed = function() {
    return _buttonsArray[1];
  };
  var _isScrolling = function() {
    return _isScrolling;
  };

  var _clearScrollInterval = function() {
    clearInterval(_scrollInterval);
  };

  return {
    init: _init,
    isLeftPressed: _isLeftPressed,
    isRightPressed: _isRightPressed,
    isMiddlePressed: _isMiddlePressed,
    isScrolling: _isScrolling,
    clearScrollInterval: _clearScrollInterval
  };
})();

MouseUtils.init(window, document);

while(MouseUtils.isLeftPressed) {
   // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: Lol, I did this question 5 years ago, not longer using prototypejs. but thanks I guess. btw everybody in SO do thing for free, so is a little senseless your comment about being free :P.